# Problem fields custom date, time, and checkbox

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I created a custom post type with custom date, time and checkbox fields.
I'm having a problem with the date and time fields that do not register in WordPress Administration or in the database.
And also there is a problem with a custom checkbox field that gets me a value but if I check two values, only one value appears, and no registration in the Wordpress administrator.

I've attached my code:

```
class Fastcat_Metabox
{

    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $post_type;
    private $fields = [];
//Ajout uploader image parti organisateur 
public static function addJS(){
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function(){
        wp_register_script('uploaderjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/uplaoder.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('uploaderjs');
    });
}

/**
 * Fastcat_Metabox constructor.
 *  @param $id ID de la boite
 *  @param $title Titre de la boite
 *  @param $post_type Post type
 */

//  Construction de la function
    public function __construct($id , $title, $post_type)
    {
        add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'create'));
        add_action('save_post', array(&$this, 'save'));

        $this->id = $id;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->post_type = $post_type;
    }
// Création de la fontion
    public function create(){
        if(function_exists('add_meta_box')) {
            add_meta_box($this->id , $this->title, array(&$this, 'render'), $this->post_type);
        }

//Sauvegarde des données et vérification des permission et du nonce 
    public function save($post_id){

    //On ne fais rien en  cas de save Ajax
            if(

                (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) ||
                (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)


            ){
                return false;
            }

          //Vérifier permission 

            if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)){
                return false;
            }


          //On vérifie le nonce 

          if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST[$this->id . '_nonce'], $this->id)){
                return false;
          }



// Vérification de toutes les publications , suppression pour remplacement si déjà existant , ajout si nouveau etc         
foreach($this->fields as $field) {
    $meta = $field['id'];
        if(isset($_POST[$meta])){
            $value = $_POST[$meta];
        if(get_post_meta($post_id, $meta)){

            update_post_meta($post_id, $meta, $value);
     } else {

            if ($value === '') {

            delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta);

        } else {

            add_post_meta($post_id, $meta , $value );

                }
            }
        }
    }      

}
// Affichage de  tout les nouveaux champs ajouter dans le dashboard 
    public function render(){

        global $post;
   foreach($this->fields as $field) {

            extract($field);

            $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $id , true);

            if($value == ''){

                $value = $default;
            }
            require __DIR__ .'/'. $field['type'] . '.php';



        }

echo '<input type="hidden" name="' .$this->id .'_nonce" value="' .wp_create_nonce($this->id). '">';
    }

// Création des nouveaux champs 
public function add($id, $label, $type = 'text', $default='') {

        $this->fields[] = [
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $label,
            'type' => $type,
            'default' => $default
        ];
                        return $this;
    }
}

Fastcat_Metabox::addJS();
// CUSTOM POST TYPE -> COMPETITION -> Ajout des parties Information et Date supplémentaire
$box = new Fastcat_Metabox('compet' , 'Compétition', 'competition');
$box->add('fastcat_adresse','<strong> Adresse: </strong> ')
    ->add('fastcat_date', '<strong>Date </strong> ', 'date')
    ->add('fastcat_starttime', '<strong>Heure de début </strong> ', 'time')
    ->add('fastcat_endtime', ' <strong>Heure de fin </strong>', 'timeend')
    ->add('fastcat_choice', '<strong>Choix compétitions </strong>', 'checkbox')
    ->add('fastcat_description', '<strong>Description de la compétition  </strong>', 'textarea')
    ->add('fastcat_space', '<strong>Nombre de place </strong> ', 'number')
    ->add('fastcat_rate', '<strong>Tarif </strong>', 'rate');

$box = new Fastcat_Metabox('ition' , 'Date Supplémentaire', 'competition');
$box->add('fastcat_date2', '<strong>Date</strong> ', 'date2')
    ->add('fastcat_starttime2', '<strong>Heure de début</strong> ', 'time2')
    ->add('fastcat_endtime2', '<strong> Heure de fin </strong>', 'timeend2')
    ->add('fastcat_date3', '<strong>Date</strong> ', 'date3')
    ->add('fastcat_starttime3', '<strong>Heure de début</strong> ', 'time3')
    ->add('fastcat_endtime3', '<strong> Heure de fin</strong> ', 'timeend3');

$box = new Fastcat_Metabox('cat' , 'Organisateur', 'competition');
$box->add('fastcat_organisateur','<strong>Nom de l\'organisateur</strong>','name_organisateur')
        ->add('fastcat_picture', '<strong Image de l\'organisateur</strong>','picture_organisateur')
        ->add('fastcat_club', '<strong>Numéro de club</strong> ', 'number_club')
        ->add('fastcat_adresse','<strong> Adresse: </strong> ', 'text')
        ->add('fastcat_phone', '<strong> Téléphone </strong>', 'phone')
        ->add('fastcat_mail', '<strong>Email</strong> ', 'mail')
        ->add('fastcat_siteweb', '<strong>Site internet</strong> ', 'web')
        ->add('fastcat_description_organisateur', '<strong>Description de la compétition  </strong>', 'description');


//CHECKBOX

<div class="meta-box-item-title" style="padding-bottom:0.3rem; ">
  <?= $name; ?>
</div>

<div class="meta-box-item-content" style="padding-bottom:0.3rem; ">
  <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $id; ?>" name="<?= $id; ?>" value="Cat">
  <label for="<?= $value; ?>" style="padding-right:1rem;">CAT</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $id; ?>" name="<?= $id; ?>" value="FastCat">
  <label for="<?= $value; ?>">FASTCAT</label>
</div>

//DATE
<div class="meta-box-item-title" style="padding-bottom:0.3rem; ">
    <?= $name; ?>
</div>

<div class="meta-box-item-content" style="padding-bottom:0.3rem; ">
    <input type="text" name="<?= $id; ?>" id="<?= $id; ?>" value="<?= $value; ?>">
</div>




//TIME
<div class="meta-box-item-title" style="padding-bottom:0.3rem; ">
    <?= $name; ?>
</div>

<div class="meta-box-item-content" style="padding-bottom:0.3rem; ">
    <input type="text" name="<?= $id; ?>" id="<?= $id; ?>" value="<?= $value; ?>">
</div>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/eyayicalib.xml

Comment: Code should be part of your question or answer, and not located externally, as it gets lost there, and then the question will be useless for others.

Comment: For more information about the guidelines of this site please visit and give the [help] a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short overview of your code reveals some issues that seems to cause the problem:

Your function `save($post_id)` saves all fields added to `$fields` array.
This array if filled using function `add($id, $label, $type = 'text', $default='')`

**But the problematic fields (checkbox, date and time) are not added to fields, so not saved by your function** `save($post_id)`.

**Suggested Solution:**
Either add these problematic fields using `add()` function if possible.
**Or**   within your function `save()` capture each of the problematic fields submitted data and save to db by something like this

```
$meta = 'name_of_html_input';  //Replace name_of_html_input with actual name given in html

if( isset( $_POST[$meta] ) ){

     $value = $_POST[$meta];

     if(get_post_meta($post_id, $meta)){
          update_post_meta($post_id, $meta, $value);
     } else {

          if ($value === '') {
             delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta);
          } else {
             add_post_meta($post_id, $meta , $value );
          }
     }
}
```

I hope this may help!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you helped me to find the problem I immediately understood with your explanation

Answer (score 2):

You add metabox in the wrong way. You should use `add_meta_boxes` action hook.

```
public function __construct($id , $title, $post_type)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->post_type = $post_type;

    add_action('add_meta_boxes', array(&$this, 'create'));
    add_action('save_post', array(&$this, 'save'));
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'addJS') );
}

public function addJS()
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen && $screen->post_type == $this->post_type) 
        wp_enqueue_script('uploaderjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/uplaoder.js');
}
```

After the changes you don't need a line `Fastcat_Metabox::addJS();`.

---

> And also there is a problem with a custom checkbox field that gets me a value but if I check two values, only one value appears, and no registration in the Wordpress administrator.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<?= $id; ?>" name="<?= $id; ?>" value="Cat">
<label for="<?= $value; ?>" style="padding-right:1rem;">CAT</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="<?= $id; ?>" name="<?= $id; ?>" value="FastCat">
<label for="<?= $value; ?>">FASTCAT</label>
```

It looks like checkboxes have the same name (ID also).

Comment: I tried your solutions but nothing is done, plus I speak of input: date, time and checkbox. These are the only fields that do not register in database due to the type of input I think, Thanks anyway, if you have an idea

Comment: @JeanneThibert By mistake I put `$this` into a static method. Should work now. I copied your code, changed the `__construct` and `addJD` as in the above answer, in place of `require __DIR__ .'/'` I display the HTML from question. Reading and writing work.